# How to get Action from Webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

How to handle View in Webview(Android). example - i am loading some web page which has some Text Field and buttons. From application level how to find whether text filed is clicked or button is clicked.

Comment: You need to check communication of webview & javascript. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131502/how-to-communicate-between-webview-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Set WebViewClient on your webView .[Read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)